# Issues opening dialog on a separate thread with XAML Hosting API

Tags: c#, multithreading, uwp-xaml, desktop-bridge, windows-community-toolkit

My WPF project uses the new XAML Islands by using WPF Toolkit's WindowsXamlHost control.

It has worked well for me up until I had to create a new dialog window with another WindowsXamlHost embedded in the new window. I received an error "AttachToWindow method failed because the specified HWND descends from a different top-level window than the HWND that was previously passed" ([more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/using-the-xaml-hosting-api)).

So in order to get around this, I have to open this dialog window using a separate thread.

```
Thread windowThread = new Thread(delegate ()
{
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
        new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));

    SettingsDialogWindow dialog = new SettingsDialogWindow()
    {
    };
    dialog.Closed += (s, args) => Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);
    dialog.Show();
    Dispatcher.Run();

});
windowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
windowThread.Start();
```

But now I have issues closing this window and terminating the thread. I get another error "Unhandled exception at 0x74865D0B (ucrtbase.dll) in MyApp.WPF.Core.exe: Fatal program exit requested."

How do I properly exit this window and terminate the thread? The code snippet works fine if I remove the WindowsXamlHost:

```
    <uwpHost:WindowsXamlHost Panel.ZIndex="0"
    Grid.Row="0"
    ChildChanged="WindowsXamlHost_ChildChanged"
    InitialTypeName="MyApp.UWP.Views.Core.SettingsUserControl"/>
```

Comment: I tested this case according to your code snippet. There's no problem. It worked well. To diagnose your issue, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT, I am now able to consistently reproduce the issue in any XamlIsland project. It occurs when I use certain default controls. For example, when I have a UWP NavgiationView in my parent window's WindowsXamlHost, and then I open a new child window with another WindowsXamlHost, close the child window, and return to the parent window's controls and mouse over it, the error will occur. Since it seems consistently reproducible, I'm starting to think it's a bug with the XamlHost itself.

Comment: As I said, could you please provide a [mcve]? Then, I can diagnose it on my side. Besides, what's your OS build version and project's target/min version?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT, I added a sample project https://github.com/chanallenk/WindowsXamlHostIssue. I am using Windows 10 Pro N 1809 build 17763.316. Project targets 17763

Comment: Ok. I can reproduce this issue, but your description is unclear. You need to tell us that this issue occurs when you use 'Windows Application Packaging Project' to package your WPF application.

Comment: Please submit this issue on GitHub [Issue](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32/issues).